# no-unused-expressions in React

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I am writing a code in React which contains a search bar. The user inputs a keyword and my code shows all the results which contain that keyword. However, my code does not work and I'm getting no-unused-expressions error.

I have an array of books and whenever my user inputs a keyword, a list of books which have that keyword in their titles will show up.
Also I want my input bar to have a value at first and when the page loads, it looks for the books that have the keywoprd.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import BooksContainer from './BooksContainer';


class BookList extends React.Component {
    constructor (props){
        super(props);

        this.state ={
            books: [
                {
{"title": "aaa" ,"description" : "abcdef" , "categories" : ["xyz"]},
{"title": "abc" , "description" : "abcdef" , "categories" : ["xyzr"]},
{"title": "abcd" , "description" : "abcdef" , "categories" : ["xyzrp"]}
                  }
            ],
            searchTerm :'harry potter',
            filterDisplay : []
             };


    }

    handleChange =(e) => 
    {
        this.setState ({searchTerm: e.target.value });
        let oldList = books.map(book => {
            return {
                book: book.title.toLowerCase(), book: book.categories.toLowerCase(), book: book.description.toLowerCase()
            };
        });

        if(searchTerm !== "")
        {
            let newList = oldList.filter(book => book.title.includes(this.state.searchTerm.toLowerCase()));
            this.setState ({filterDisplay: newList });
        }
    }


    render(){ 

        return(

            <div>

                <form onSubmit = {this.handleSearch}>
                    <h6>Search for the books</h6>
                    <input type = "text"  value = {this.state.searchTerm} onChange = {this.handleChange} />
                    <button type = "submit">Search</button>
                </form>

                    <BooksContainer books ={this.state.searchTerm.length < 1 ? this.state.books:this.state.filterDisplay} />

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default BookList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well as far as I know "no-unused-expressions" is not the reason your code is not working. It is from eslint or other linter and it just mean declaring something that you didn't use in the code, not a breaking code issue: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-expressions

Of course you can add this line to your .eslintrc rules:

```
rules: {
'no-unused-expression': 0,
}
```

From what I see you should get rid off {} around your books array - lines 11 and 15.
And on line 29 you are trying to return the same key name 3 times:

```
book: book.title.toLowerCase(), book: book.categories.toLowerCase(), book: book.description.toLowerCase()
```

This first "book" is just a key and you shouldn't go with 3 same keys. Just for example this way is fine:

```
book: [book.title.toLowerCase(), book.categories.toLowerCase(), book.description.toLowerCase()]
```

The **let** oldList should be replace with **const** oldList.

The same goes for **let** newList, should be replace with **const**.